# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mode') Material React Table Next js application

Tags: next.js, material-react-table

[image]I am getting this error in a Next js application that has a  Material React Table.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import SimpleSidebar from '@/components/SideBar';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { Flex, Text, Box } from '@chakra-ui/layout';
import { MaterialReactTable, type MRT_ColumnDef } from 'material-react-table';

//example data type
type Person = {
  name: {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
  };
  address: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
};

const data: Person[] = [
  {
    name: {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe'
    },
    address: '261 Erdman Ford',
    city: 'East Daphne',
    state: 'Kentucky'
  },
  {
    name: {
      firstName: 'Jane',
      lastName: 'Doe'
    },
    address: '769 Dominic Grove',
    city: 'Columbus',
    state: 'Ohio'
  },
  {
    name: {
      firstName: 'Joe',
      lastName: 'Doe'
    },
    address: '566 Brakus Inlet',
    city: 'South Linda',
    state: 'West Virginia'
  },
  {
    name: {
      firstName: 'Kevin',
      lastName: 'Vandy'
    },
    address: '722 Emie Stream',
    city: 'Lincoln',
    state: 'Nebraska'
  },
  {
    name: {
      firstName: 'Joshua',
      lastName: 'Rolluffs'
    },
    address: '32188 Larkin Turnpike',
    city: 'Omaha',
    state: 'Nebraska'
  }
];

const Statements: React.FC = () => {
  const columns = React.useMemo<MRT_ColumnDef<Person>[]>(
    () => [
      {
        accessorKey: 'name.firstName', //access nested data with dot notation
        header: 'First Name',
        size: 150
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'name.lastName',
        header: 'Last Name',
        size: 150
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'address', //normal accessorKey
        header: 'Address',
        size: 200
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'city',
        header: 'City',
        size: 150
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'state',
        header: 'State',
        size: 150
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <SimpleSidebar location="statements">
      <Head>
        <title>Staff Dashboard | Notes</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Description goes here" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Flex align="center" h="95px" bg="white" pl="30px">
        <Text as="h2" mb="0">
          All Statements
        </Text>
      </Flex>
      <Box>
        <MaterialReactTable columns={columns} data={data} />;
      </Box>
    </SimpleSidebar>
  );
};

export default Statements;
```

I tried to check if the Material Ui V5 packages in my project were matching what is needed for material-react-table and they were mathing. I also uninstalled the roject dependnecies and re-isntalled a fresh.
I created a new next js project separately and it worked okay.